# Fluid render has horizontal lines in Blender Eevee

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

I am trying to render a fluid simulation in blender eevee but horizontal lines appear in every frame. Can someone help me out?
  [image]

Comment: It's been a while, did you figure out what was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was testing fluid simulation here and had the same issue. The solution was to turn off "Show Backface" in the Material settings tab, under "Settings" like in the screenshot below. Then the lines don't show up anymore.

[image: screenshot]